# I can not solve TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, list, runtime-error, tuples

I want to remove all the transactions between day1 and day2 in a list of tuples, that describe a transaction. A transaction has an amount, a day and a type. When I run this I get the error

> "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable" on row 4.

Can anybody help me?

```
def delete_periodoftime(transactions, day1, day2):
    for i,transaction in enumerate(transactions):
        if i['Day']<=day1 or i['Day']<=day2:
            transactions.remove(i)
```

Comment: `i['Day']` `i` is your count, not your item, maybe `transaction['Day']`

Comment: You also shouldn't remove from a list you iterate on.

Comment: Oh, let me give it a try.

Comment: to expand on @polku on why you shouldn't be doing what you are doing, http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/3553/common-pitfalls/949/changing-the-sequence-you-are-iterating-over#t=201610281423442624758

Comment: MooingRawr thank you so much! I used transaction['Day'] and it worked, I have another function which deletes transactions from a single day and instead of "for i,transaction in enumerate(transactions):" it uses "for i in transactions:" and I thought it works the same way.

Comment: You should make a new list and put items into that or use list comprehension to generate a new list. Rule of thumb, don't iterate over something and remove things in it because in short: you may skip over items.

Comment: Does iterating backwards in the list work in my case?

Comment: So modifying the iteration to "for i,transaction in reversed(enumerate(list(transactions))):"

Comment: Please read what I linked, there's a solution there.... in short yes, you can.... but follow the syntax provided in the example.

Comment: Also it should have been "if i['Day']>=day1 or i['Day']<=day2:" to get the transactions between, not under both day1 and day 2 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to filter these transactions by the day. Another good way of doing it is with a list comprehension.

```
def delete_periodoftime(transactions, day1, day2):
    return [t for t in transactions if t['Day'] <= day1 or t['Day'] <= day2]
```

The difference between this and your current code is that this is creating and returning a new list instead of mutating the one passed into the function.

Therefore, if you were calling the function like `delete_periodoftime(my_transactions, my_day1, my_day2)`, you would now need to call it like `my_transactions = delete_periodoftime(my_transactions, my_day1, my_day2)`.

Although this is more code, it is advantageous because you can use this function when you need the results somewhere else and you don't want to change your transaction list. Additionally, the list comprehension is often more clear.